# slow mysql database restore with multiple threads (delphi)

Tags: mysql, multithreading, performance, delphi, restore

I need to restore a lot of mysql database backups and I've been trying to speed up by using multiple threads (in Delphi), each with their own connection.  When I'm using MODE_SCRIPT, I can only process around 1 file per second (fps), with the CPU/DISK/MEMORY not stressed at all

When I'm using MODE_CMD, I can get as high as 12+fps with the CPU up to 100% on all cores.

It looks like when using TClientDataSet or descendants, the script is not using all cores, even when using multiple threads?

Minimal code example:

```
type
  TWorker = class(TThread)
  private
    FTasks: TThreadStringList;
    FConn: TMyConnection;
    FScript: TMyScript;
    FQ: TMyQuery;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    procedure addTask(const aFn: String);
    constructor create(Suspended: Boolean; const aMyId: LongInt;const aIniDb: TIniDBSettings);
  end;

procedure TWorker.addTask(const aFn: String);
begin
  FTasks.Add(aFn);
end;

constructor TWorker.create(Suspended: Boolean; const aMyId: LongInt; const aIniDb: TIniDBSettings);
begin
  inherited Create(Suspended);
  FTasks := TMTThreadStringList.Create;
  FMyName := 'WORKER__'+IntToStr(aMyId);
end;

procedure TWorker.Execute;
var
  mode: LongInt;
const
    MODE_DOS=1;
    MODE_SCRIPT = 2;
begin  
  FConn := TMyConnection.Create(Nil);
  FConn.Username := aIniDb.iniSDBUsername;
  FConn.Password := aIniDb.iniSDBPass;
  FConn.Database := aIniDb.iniSDBDatabase;
  FConn.Server := aIniDb.iniSDBServer;

  FScript := TMyScript.Create(Nil);
  FScript.Connection := FConn;

    try
        FConn.Connect;
        while not Terminated do begin
          if FTasks.Count > 0 then begin
            tmpFn := FTasks.Strings[0];
            FTasks.Delete(0);

            fMyDbname := 'tmpdb_'+FMyName;

            if(mode=MODE_SCRIPT) then {
                FQ.SQL.Text := 'drop database if exists '+fMyDbname ;
                FQ.Execute;
                FQ.SQL.Text := 'create database '+fMyDbname;
                FQ.Execute;
                FQ.SQL.Text := 'use '+fMyDbname;
                fQ.Execute;
                FScript.SQL.LoadFromFile(tmpFn+'.new');
                FScript.Execute;
            }
            else if(mode=MODE_DOS) then begin
                sCmd := 'cmd.exe /c mysql -u user -h serverip < '+tmpFn;
                GetDosOutput(sCmd,dosOutput);//function using 'CreateProcess()'
            }
            InterlockedIncrement(QDONE);
          end
          else Sleep(15);
        end;
      except on e: Exception do
        MessageBox(0,PWideChar('error'+e.Message),'error',MB_OK);
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: you know you can simply use mysqldump to restore files, right?

Comment: @whosrdaddy: I tried calling mysqldump from my threads too: the performance was equal.
I also tried calling CreateProcess(cmd.exe /c mysql -u root -pPassword < '+tmpFn) from my threads, but no change either

Comment: Then I don't see how you can possibly gain something using delphi, the result will always be slower. Anyway the code you presented has a number of issues. Remember that TWorker.Create and TWorker.Destroy run in the context of the main thread, so all you db connections are created on the main thread. Also what is the FQ variable, I dont see it created anywhere in the code?

Comment: I'm using Delphi because for each DB that gets restored, I need to  process the result.I tested with batch files (mysql -u root -pPassword < filename):
1batch restoring 300 files=660"
6batches*50 lines=255"(1.1fps)
 
With 9 TWorker threads in delphi on the same machine I get 3fps.However,CPU& disk activity are low, both for the batch files or when running the threads and I can't figure out where the bottleneck is.

Good point on the creation of the connection: I moved it to the start of the execute loop.  At first glance it's not spectactularly faster, I'm still getting only +/- 3.5 fps.

Comment: Maybe there isn't more to gain? You will have to do some profiling on MySQL I guess...

Comment: It's hard to imagine that this is the limit of mysql.  When I'm running my test on the server machine (12 cores, 24 gb ram), I can only process 0.5 fps up to 1.8 fps, no matter how many threads.  But there is no stress to be seen in task manager on the disk/cpu...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using MyISAM.  That is antiquated, and suffers from "table locks", which inhibits much in the way of parallelism.

The following are irrelevant for MyISAM:

```
-SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
-SET autocommit=0;
```

Some questions that relate to the problem:

- Do you have `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns?
- Are you inserting into the same table at the same time from different threads?  (Problematic with MyISAM and MEMORY, less so with InnoDB.)
- How many `UNIQUE` keys on each table?  (`INSERTs` are slowed down by the need to check for dups.)
- Are you using `INSERT`?  One row at a time?  Or batched?  (Inserting a batch of 100 rows at a time is about optimal -- 10 times as fast as 1 at a time.)
- Or are you using `LOAD DATA`?  (Even faster.)
- What is the relationship between a "file" and a "table"?  That is, are you loading lots of little files into a table, or each file is one table?
- Does the RAID have striping and/or a Battery Backed Write Cache?
- Is the disk HDD or SSD?
- What is the ping time between the client and server?  (You mentioned "network", but gave no indication of proximity.)
- How many tables?  Are you creating up to 1.87 tables per second?  That is 3 files to write and 1 to read?  (Windows is not the greatest at rapid opening of files.)  That's about 7 file opens/sec.  (Note InnoDB needs only 1 file per table if using `innodb_file_per_table=1`.)

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for a couple of the larger tables.  Please provide a sample of the SQL statements used.

Wilson's request could also be handy.

Comment: Thank you Rick James and whosrdaddy for all those considerations.  The bottleneck is when using a restore through a TClientDataset (or descendant).  Using CreateProcess with the mysql command gives me much higher speed (I must have overlooked when I first tested this). I edited the info in my initial post.